# download attribute not working in gitbook

Tags: gitbook

In markdown, I specify the download attribute for a file link to download the file when clicking on the link

```
<a href="https://ojv8yfncs.qnssl.com/fundebug.0.1.2.min.js" download target="_self">fundebug.0.1.2.min.js</a>t
```

But it is not working. After run "gitbook serve", the link will be opened in a new tab.

I checked the html which gitbook generates, it add **target="_blank"**：

```
<a href="https://ojv8yfncs.qnssl.com/fundebug.0.1.2.min.js" download="" target="_blank">fundebug.0.1.2.min.js</a>
```

I tried to override target attribute by specify **target="_self"**, but it is not working.

Comment: Where is the actual MarkDown? All you have shown is HTML. Or are you saying that you inserted HTML directly?

Comment: yes, I insert html in markdown